# Java: Using my for statement

Tags: java

this is my first post so please bear with me. I am trying to produce a program that lets a user play black jack against the computer. the following code let the player take their turn:

```
//method for the players turn
    public static void playersTurn()
    {
        String playersCard = dealSingleCard();
        playerHand.add(playersCard);
        String playersActualHand = cardRepresentation(playersCard);
        System.out.println(playersActualHand);
        //System.out.println(playerHand);
        System.out.println(calculateHandValue(playerHand));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Stick or Twist?");
        String stickOrTwist = in.next();
        String twist = "t";
        String stick = "s";
        //int total = 0;
        //int playerTotal = calculateHandValue(playerHand) + total;

        if (calculateHandValue(playerHand) < 21)
        {
            if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (twist));
            {
                dealSingleCard();

            }

        if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (stick))
                {
                    calculateWinner();
                }
        }

    }
```

I cant seem to get the "twist" if statement to work, the program just stops. The "stick if statement work fine. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (twist));` - remove the `;`

Answer (score 3):

You have a little syntax error, since you put a semicolon after the if condition, here:

```
if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (twist));
```

Remove it and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Change the below code

```
if (calculateHandValue(playerHand) < 21)
{
     if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (twist));
     {
         dealSingleCard();
     }
     if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (stick))
     {
          calculateWinner();
     }
}
```

with

```
if (calculateHandValue(playerHand) < 21)
{
     if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (twist))
     {
         dealSingleCard();
     }
     if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (stick))
     {
          calculateWinner();
     }
}
```

The line terminator ';' should not be used with the if condition.

Answer (score 1):

the only problem with your code is that you have placed ';' after the if statemt.So the compiler is not executing the body of if.Try removing the semicolon as:

```
           if (stickOrTwist .equalsIgnoreCase (twist))
            {
                dealSingleCard();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules of blackjack (or pontoon as it was called when I was growing up) are that a player can repeatedly twist until (s)he either decides to stick or her hand value exceeds 21.  This repeated behaviour is absent from your code.

Instead of

```
if (calculateHandValue(playerHand) < 21)
```

you should have a loop

```
while (calculateHandValue(playerHand) < 21)
```

and inside the while loop, you ask if the player will stick or twist.  Break out of the loop if the player sticks and then process the bust condition.  You should only call the  `calculateWinner()` method once all the players have played.

Answer (score 0):

I just assume from the way you used dealSingleCard() at the beginning of the methode, you want todo the following:

```
if(stickOrTwist.equalsIgnoreCase(twist)){
            playerHand.add(dealSingleCard());
}
```